# How to copy the email addresses of all intended recipients in an email draft in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook.com

How to copy the email addresses of all intended recipients in an email draft at once in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

[image]

I tried:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: it does nothing. (that's the keyboard shortcut that Gmail uses, and probably many other email clients)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>: it only copies one email address at a time.